# $f$ entire and $f(n) = n$ with $\lim_{|z| \to \infty} |f(z)| = \infty$, show $f(z) = z$

Tags: complex-analysis

The question is: $f$ entire and $f(n) = n$ with $\lim_{|z| \to \infty} |f(z)| = \infty$, show $f(z) = z$.

I know that $f$ must be a polynomial which can be deduced from just the entire and $\lim_{|z| \to \infty} |f(z)| = \infty$ hypothesis. However, I do not see how to use the $f(n) = n$ for each $n$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks, it is fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(z)-z$ is a polynomial with infinitely many zeros. Hence it is identically $0$.

Comment: Ah, thanks I should have seen this